# Setting up an Ethereum Light Wallet

Tags: wallets, windows

I want to set up an Ethereum LIGHT Wallet (because I mainly don't want to keep the system running for a week or so to get the blockchain on my computer) on my Windows7 system. Therefore I found a posting on Reddit but can't discuss the topic there because I've got insufficient rights to post there ...

So mainly I've started "geth.exe" with the parameter "-light" which gave me this output here:

> INFO [08-24|01:03:14] Starting peer-to-peer node
>   instance=Geth/v1.6.5-stable-cf87713d/windows-amd64/go1.8.3
>   INFO [08-24|01:03:14] Allocated cache and file handles
>   database=C:\Users\Wini\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\lightchaindata
>   cache=128 handles=1024
>   INFO [08-24|01:03:14] Initialised chain
>   configuration config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000
>   DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000
>   Metropolis: 9223372036854775807 Engine: ethash}"
>   INFO [08-24|01:03:14]
>   Disk storage enabled for ethash caches
>   dir=C:\Users\Wini\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\ethash count=3 INFO
>   [08-24|01:03:14] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs
>   dir=C:\Users\Wini\AppData\Ethash count=2
>  INFO [08-24|01:03:14] Added
>   trusted CHT for mainnet 
> INFO [08-24|01:03:14] Loaded most recent local
>   header number=0 hash=d4e567.cb8fa3 td=17179869184 INFO
>   [08-24|01:03:14] Starting P2P networking 
> WARN [08-24|01:03:14] Light
>   client mode is an experimental feature 
> INFO [08-24|01:03:14] RLPx
>   listener up
>   self="enode://877f41f91d435bd9f8cf921c499fbf08387da1a8cfa1b63c09dbc8b272535f10d3843c1f6ed35516ca18213b1110dad0c1b43f5d7f2fde04121eee1385d652bd@[::]:30303?discport=0"
>   
> INFO [08-24|01:03:14] IPC endpoint opened: .\pipe\geth.ipc 2017/08/24
>   01:03:16 ssdp: got unexpected search target result "upnp:rootdevice"
>   2017/08/24 01:03:16 ssdp: got unexpected search target result
>   "uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-0017881a3b22" 2017/08/24 01:03:16 ssdp:
>   got unexpected search target result
>   "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:basic:1" 2017/08/24 01:03:16 ssdp: got
>   unexpected search target result "upnp:rootdevice" 2017/08/24 01:03:16
>   ssdp: got unexpected search target result
>   "uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-0017881a3b22" 2017/08/24 01:03:16 ssdp:
>   got unexpected search target result
>   "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:basic:1"

Don't know if there is already something wrong? After this I was starting the "ethereum wallet.exe" with the parameters "-node-light", then the splash screen is showing and the message "Looking for peers...." is shown. That's it - nothing more happens. Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?